# Am I getting the signature_base correct?

Tags: .net, oauth, etrade-api

I'm getting logged in correctly and getting the pin now, so I still count that as progress.
Can someone check the strings I'm encrypting?
What else could 'bad request' mean?

First, I get the AccessToken,
which generates this signature base

> 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085%26oauth_nonce%3D565e334127934d65aa4375d0cd2770a1%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1502146468%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

Then it calls SignContext which executes this line

```
signingContext.SignatureBase = authContext.GenerateSignatureBase();
```

which generates this signature base

> 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085%26oauth_nonce%3D565e334127934d65aa4375d0cd2770a1%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1502146468%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

Then it gets the pin.

Then it calls ExchangeRequestTokenForAccessToken
which generates this signature base

> 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085%26oauth_nonce%3De63bba497c24492ab0d60366526c781a%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1502146597%26oauth_token%3D6WHEWvcaVYx59bRxzic%252FXJGGYrz4TGdH5uvlfNCdkOY%253D%26oauth_verifier%3DNHD85%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

Then it signs the context again using this signature base

> 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085%26oauth_nonce%3De63bba497c24492ab0d60366526c781a%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1502146597%26oauth_token%3D6WHEWvcaVYx59bRxzic%252FXJGGYrz4TGdH5uvlfNCdkOY%253D%26oauth_verifier%3DNHD85%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

Then I try to get the quote for A
with this signature base

> 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetws.etrade.com%2Fmarket%2Frest%2Fquote%2FA&detailFlag%3DALL%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085%26oauth_nonce%3D4a3640c5fc5c40b490c475a2e6c0228e%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1502146666%26oauth_token%3D77vmxV1reXdgDJewWspVKmOduwdDsZGVvLfZBUtBSms%253D%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

It fails on retrieving the quote and returns:

> 8/7/2017 5:57:46 PM -  Header Start     8/7/2017 5:58:18 PM - 
>   Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_token='77xmvV1reXdgDJewWspVKmOduwdDsZGVvLfZUBtBSms%3D',oauth_nonce='4a3640c5fc5c40b490c475a2e6c0228e',oauth_consumer_key='c5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085',oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1',oauth_timestamp='1502146666',oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature='2OihTU%2BphJjPuvp82lR8Z2QhE24%3D'
>   8/7/2017 5:58:18 PM -  Header End     8/7/2017 5:58:18 PM - 
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at EquityMetrics.Retrieve.ETradeModel.GetResponse(OAuthSession
>   session, String url) in C:{path}\Model\ETradeModel.cs:line 94
>   8/7/2017 5:58:18 PM -  Pragma: no-cache       apiServerName: 11w44m3
>   nnCoection: close     Transfer-Encoding: chunked     Cache-Control:
>   no-cache, no-store      Content-Type: application/xml     Date: Mon,
>   07 Aug 2017 22:58:18 GMT     Server: Apache

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong with it,iIs the actual URL you are sending to 'https://etws.etrade.com/market/rest/quote/A&detailFlag=ALL'? Is this your own code or libraries provided by Etrade? Also note detailFlag = ALL is default, so you can leave that out and give it a try. You can also put the headers as URL parameters instead and enter it directly in to browser to rule out a code issue.

Comment: AFAIK, etrade doesn't supply anything besides rough instructions. The encryption and the signature base are deep inside the oauth library. My code is calling the oauth code. I've been stuck at this point for almost a month and the etrade API support group hasn't been able to help.

Comment: Since I'm getting bad request, it seems possible that something about the request that is getting encrypted is wrong. But I don't see it.

Comment: The URL is "https://etws.etrade.com/market/rest/quote/A?detailFlag=ALL"

Comment: Im guessing its not the signature since you would get invalid_signature error. I think Bad Request implies some bad request header/values which is why I suggested entering in browser (should work in Chrome), and getting rid of detail flag parameter to create a simpler test. I noticed one other thing, I'll put it in an answer

Comment: I finally noticed that your question had '&' before the parameter while my answer had '?'.  I thought we were onto something. But no. That is how parameters are required to be appended by the Oauth spec. I'll try the browser again. No luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I hit the URL from the browser I started getting better error messages and that led to the solution. But it is not obvious how to do that.

For this header:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="c6154d11e1a0a29301d75e7aa1993085",oauth_nonce="simTGhOB4T7",oauth_signature="Dij6ZXwcBda78Rk54K3k3UUfGMc%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1505152250",oauth_token="DnMnZQTQUqaJxAFJNwTy76lEaP5toiWt2QeI4POZnKY%3D",oauth_version="1.0"
```

Use this URL in the browser to get better error messages:

```
https://etws.etrade.com/market/rest/quote/A?oauth_consumer_key=c6154d11e1a0a29301d75e7aa1993085&oauth_nonce=simTGhOB2T7&oauth_signature=Dij6ZXwcBda78Rk54K3k3UUfGMc%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1505152250&oauth_token=DnMnZQTQUqaJxAFJNwTy76lEaP5toiWt2QeI4POZnKY%3D&oauth_version=1.0
```

OTOH, The sort order doesn't appear to matter, outside the base for the signature, as stated in the spec.

Comment: Thanks to @kingdc for proving the clue that led to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Oauth 1.0 spec](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_header), the authorization header should use ascii value 34, which is a double quote, not a single quote. The parameters should also be sorted alphabetically by name. In the error message above it looks like it is using single quotes and unsorted parameters. It should look like the following (line breaks added for readability):

```
Authorization: OAuth 
oauth_token="77xmvV1reXdgDJewWspVKmOduwdDsZGVvLfZUBtBSms%3D",  
oauth_nonce="4a3640c5fc5c40b490c475a2e6c0228e",  
oauth_consumer_key="c5164d11e1a0a23901d75e7aa1993085",
oauth_signature="2OihTU%2BphJjP",  
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",  
oauth_timestamp="1502146666",  
oauth_version="1.0"
```

Comment: You are correct. They are double quotes in the original. I changed it to single quotes to post to the etrade API group, since they don't allow ". I didn't think to change it back when I posted here after they didn't answer. Good catch.

Comment: Do the headers count as parameters? Nevermind. They are in alpha order already. So that's not it.

Comment: I meant the parameters within the 'authorization' header. For example oauth_signature is not in order.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse. I see detailFlag, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version which looks right to me. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: After oauth_version I see oauth_signature, which should be located before oauth_signature_method. Added example above.

Comment: I see. I was looking at the base that gets encrypted, not the headers. Looking through the spec, I see several examples where the sig is included in the request, but none where it is included in the base. The closest I could find to a reference is this where it is excluded: "
Appendix A.5.1.  Generating Signature Base String - To generate the signature, it first needs to generate the Signature Base String. The request contains the following parameters (oauth_signature excluded) which are ordered and concatenated into a normalized string: "

Comment: I don't see anything about the headers themselves being ordered, just the parameters in the base. Is that a requirement?

Comment: In all examples I've seen they are in order as well, but if that doesn't fix it then I have no further ideas. I still think its simpler to test using URL params with no detailFlag, but if even that doesn't work you may have to try some other approaches for oauth and/or http request sending. Good luck.